# How to remove 'www' from all url of wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using woocommerce for  my web store since few months and just before few days I have enabled multisite in my web store.

I have followed [this](http://www.tcbarrett.com/2013/07/how-to-remove-www-from-your-wordpress-network-multisite-primary-domain/#.WSLqwVR97IV) link to remove 'www' from url just because Woocommerce REST API was not working without 'www'. Now REST API working perfect but when am going to open dashboard, products etc. for particular site from network admin am getting below error

> This has been disabled

but when I remove www manually from url it's working good. So how can I remove www from all url of admin panel? Because am getting above error also when am going to add new product or new category. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this via wp-config.php and functions.php of theme

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

functions.php

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Replace the URL with your current site URL. It will work.

Comment: Its not working. I think wp-config.php changes are covered in [this](http://www.tcbarrett.com/2013/07/how-to-remove-www-from-your-wordpress-network-multisite-primary-domain/#.WSPVAVSGPIW) link which I followed.

Comment: `Update wp_options.option_value (where option_name=siteurl)` and `Update wp_options.option_value (where option_name=home)` these both changes I already did in db

Comment: Try this in .htaccess : RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` this code is already there in my .htaccess. Can I update it or need to rewrite?

Comment: :( Not working yet. Now it's redirecting all dashboard of multisite to parent site.

Answer (score 0):

there is an another way to replace all url in database.

Please use wordpress plugin "go update live url".

https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/

Here you can see two option, first is for Old Url and second it New url.

and in last click on update/submit button and you will see that All wordpress urls will be update as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have solved issue by recreating all multisites.